# R returns more coefficients than expected in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am using a dataset from a website to check logistic regression. R returns three coefficients for the variable "age" Below is the dataset. The age variable has four levels: <25, 25-29, 30-39, 40-49.

[data](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat)

The dataset has three predictor variables (i.e., age, education, wantsMore). The fourth and the fifth columns are the response variables, corresponding to "No" (the fourth column) and "Yes" (the fifth column).

[image: data]

When I use this dataset to perform logistic regression, I am getting more coefficients for the age variable.

```
cuse = read.table("https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat", header = TRUE)

cuse$age=factor(cuse$age)

lrfit = glm( cbind(using, notUsing) ~ age + education + wantsMore,
             data = cuse, family = binomial)

lrfit$coefficients
```

The coefficient are shown below. R produces three coefficients for age variable. How can I fix it?

```
> lrfit$coefficients
 (Intercept)     age25-29     age30-39     age40-49 educationlow wantsMoreyes 
  -0.8082200    0.3893816    0.9086135    1.1892389   -0.3249947   -0.8329548
```

Comment: That's what I would expect to see.  Are you expecting to only see one parameter? Your data isn't continuous.

Comment: The age variable has four levels. I use factor() to convert age into a categorical variable. So there should be just ONE coefficient.

Comment: ... I think you're confused.  Categorical variables will get (k-1) coefficients where k is the number of levels in the variable.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. If I use (1, 2, 3, 4) to encode the four levels of age, how can I obtain just one coefficient for the age variable.

Comment: I don't think that would be a good approach from a modeling standpoint.  Seriously - it sounds like you should talk to a statistician.  But if you did that then you would just use that encoding directly in the model instead of the categorical version of age.

Comment: Then what does the factor() function do in this case? I think the four levels have been properly encoded with factor() function.

Comment: I agree with what @Dason said.  If you've got categorical data like this and you're using the numerical values 1, 2, 3, 4 to represent them, then you're assuming that whatever the effect of being category 1 is (<25 from your data), you'll get twice that effect for category 2 (25-29), three times the effect for category 3, and so on.  In general, that's not an assumption you want to make with categorical data.

Comment: If you want a single *p-value* (not coefficient) for the combined effect of age, you can use `anova()` or `drop1()` or `car::Anova()` or ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Dason mentioned in the comments, you will get `k-1` coefficients for you `k` number of ranks in your categorical variable, `age`.

This is because internally, R creates [dummy variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) in order to deal with categorical variables. In a regression model, it doesn't make sense to multiply a numerical coefficient value with a "category" of "age less than 25".

So dummy variables are used to encode them in a way so you can do this coefficient multiplication. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276290/dummy-variables-in-logistic-regression) for more discussion on it.

For your model, the last "missing" variable for age is the baseline variable that all the other ages are being compared to, namely an `age` of `<25`. So, based on your modeling, an individual with an `age` of `25-29`, versus the baseline of `<25`, changes the log odds of your response variables (`notUsing` and `using`) by `0.3893816`.

See [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) for an in-depth tutorial that has a category variable (theirs is `rank`) and how to interpret it.